# Automatically make changes to a github file

Tags: github, bots, discord, telegram, telegram-bot

I’ve Made an app whith a whitelist, the withelist is on a github repo ( with just one file that is the withelist ), Each time that a user that downloads my app want to be allowed to use the app has to send me a message for be inserted in the white list.  Right now this process is really slow and I want to speed it up but I’m trying to figure out how. I’m sesrching a way for

- Let the users send me a message
- Read the message ( with a bot or something that automate this process )
- Make the bot add the user to the whitelist

I’m having some troubles to find a ‘free’ way for do it. The first ideas that came in my mind were to do it with a discord server or a Telegram group, but i didn’t find something for make the bot able to commit changes to a github file. Another problem would be that this messages are readable by all the users becouse are sent in a discord/telegram group and I want to keep them private. There is some simpler ways for do something like this?