# Discord bot that commits to github

Tags: python, git, github, discord, discord.py

I made previously a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002236/automatically-make-changes-to-a-github-file) about how to manage 'dynamically' a whitelist from github by using a bot (actually I received no answers but I made a discord one).

So I have a github repo where all the users that wants to use my app has to be allows to do that. This is done by a discord bot (built with the Python discord module).

When the user want to be added to the white list he has to send a DM command to the bot. As this all the user can manage their own accounts from the white list.

Actually I did in this wait:

- create a git repo on my pc
- activate the discord bot ( also from my pc )
- Each time that the bot receives a add-account / remove-account command it edits the whitelist file
- Each hour it commits the changes the it made to the file to github.

But I'm trying to understand if it has some serious 'security' problems, like if anyone can see the bot source code and change it or things like that.

Also, right now the Push of the committed changes is done by a python script that execute this commands

- `os.system('git add .')`
- `os.system('git commit -m "whitelist changes. From discord bot')`
- `os.system('git push origin master')`

It shouldn't be too bad from my point of view but i don't know if it is risky to do this task in this way

Comment: Do you have a question? Please focus on a specific error or problem that you ran into.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your source code I can't say anything specifically, but here's some general comments.

Shell commands open up a lot of potential security problems. If you pass unfiltered user input to the shell malicious users can take advantage. For example, let's say you want to allow users to make a branch.

```
command = 'git branch %s' % (branch_name)
os.system(command)
```

This allows a user to execute code like 'foo; echo 0wned'

To avoid this, avoid `os.system` which uses the shell to execute commands. Instead use `subprocess.run` which requires you to pass in the command and its arguments.

```
subprocess.run(["git", "branch", branch_name])
```

This does not use a shell and is safe from malicious branch names.

Better yet, avoid running commands altogether and use a library to talk to Git like [pygit2](https://www.pygit2.org/). It's faster and easier to deal with errors, though it can be a little unfamiliar.

---

Your Discord bot having access to your Github account exposes your Github account. There's no need for the bot to push to Github. Write a separate command which periodically pushes to Github. A simple scheduled job will do.

---

Finally, using Git and Github as a database is very awkward. I'm not sure I understand what the whitelist is for, or why it needs to be on Github. If you just want to store some data for free, many hosting services provide free tiers. [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/), for example, offers "hobby tier" hosting.